# A PHP and jQuery form creation and validation library available?

Tags: php, jquery, validation, forms

### Original Question

Is there a well tested and preferably mature library out there for creating forms in PHP with both client side (this is where the jQuery comes in) and server side validation?

Ideally the form would either be generated from PHP classes or written as plain HTML and parsed ala [Agavi](http://www.agavi.org). The correct jQuery hooks would then automatically be created by the library so that the included jQuery client side validation can run.

One of the jobs I do regularly is some variation on the good old contact form and I would like to standardise this work so that I can trot out the same best practice code each time. With this in mind the HTML generated by the PHP classes should be good enough so that extra CSS hooks can be added where needed etc.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

---

### Update

I have been combing through and reviewing the options that I have found and that others have suggested below and at the moment I would rank the projects in the following order for quality from the small amount of testing and research I have done on all of them.

1. [ValidForm Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362842/a-php-and-jquery-form-creation-and-validation-library-available/5389651#5389651)
2. [jFormer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362842/a-php-and-jquery-form-creation-and-validation-library-available/5363589#5363589)
3. [HTML_QuickForm2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362842/a-php-and-jquery-form-creation-and-validation-library-available/5367480#5367480) (if you can get the client side validation working then this should jump higher than jFormer!)
4. [php-form-builder-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362842/a-php-and-jquery-form-creation-and-validation-library-available/5362972#5362972)
5. [Use Symfony!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362842/a-php-and-jquery-form-creation-and-validation-library-available/5428229#5428229) (a whole MVC framework for form rendering and validation is overkill)

I am still unconvinced by any of the options to be honest and I am left wondering why people who embark on these projects do not start with some solid and well tested components. For example I would have thought a combination of:

- [Parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org) Client side validation
- [Symfony form](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms/overview.html) component perhaps
- Perhaps with [Respect Validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation)

Would give you a good stable base to work from and produce a nice library on top of tested components.

Also if you are interested in a library that parses your HTML rather than generating the HTML from a PHP class I have found a project called [Minacl](https://github.com/mellowplace/Minacl). Like the [Agavi](http://www.agavi.org) option I mentioned in the original question.

Comment: I'll be interested in the answers you get. Most of the stuff I find is either a very thin wrapper around what is already there (while also blocking some of the normal functionality), or is so byzantine that it takes longer than doing it by hand.

Comment: Have you found a suitable library yet? I'm looking for one as well, and so far VFB seems like it's the best but it hasn't updated for over a year and a half.

Comment: @Jon I am using VFB and there has been activity in the last year - see: http://code.google.com/p/validformbuilder/source/list

Comment: Hi. I have just recently completed open source PHP UI Toolkit : http://agiletoolkit.org/. It took me 2 years to build but it comes with the most cutting-edge server-side form builder. If you like it - please include in your list.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [ValidForm Builder](http://validformbuilder.org/). It matches perfect to your requirements: 
With it you can define Forms with validation rules in PHP, and it generates the Forms with jQuery and client side validation.

Feature List (taken from their site):

- The API generates XHTML Strict 1.0 compliant code.
- Field validation on the client side to minimize traffic overhead.
- Field validation on the server side to enforce validation rules and prevent tempering
  with the form through SQL injection.
- Client side validation displays inline to improve user satisfaction. No more annoying popups that don't really tell you anything.
- Easy creation of complex form structures.
- Uses the popular jQuery Javascript library for DOM manipulation.
- Completely customizable using CSS.
- Automatic creation of field summaries for form mailers in both HTML and plain text.
- It's open source and therefore completely free ([here's the GitHub repo](https://github.com/neverwoods/validformbuilder))!

Comment: Have you used this library yourself? Have you had to make any custom validation routines etc? Just curious how easy it is once it is taken off of the beaten track.

Comment: Well I used it but don't had to make custom routines I was happy with the provided.

Comment: This looks like the best option that has been recommended or that I have been able to find. However I still have some reservations over using this library. It seems to have sat at v1 for a while and there hasn't been action on issues since November last year.

Comment: never change a running system ;-)

Comment: @Tokk This is a pretty bad bug though "Slashes Showing up when form reloads" http://code.google.com/p/validformbuilder/issues/detail?id=6 and it has been kicking around for a year now. Same with this bug: "Fields of type VFORM_FILE won't validate" http://code.google.com/p/validformbuilder/issues/detail?id=8

Comment: I have given the bounty to this answer as there aren't any more answers likely to come in before the bounty is due to expire and I don't see the point in the bounty not being assigned (the highest scoring answer only gets half the bounty if you don't assign it and SO swallows up the rest of the rep!). I don't, however, feel that this is the answer to my question so I have not marked it as such. It is definitely the best answer here though. I think though that I will most likely write my own based upon Zend_Form, Uni-Form and jQuery Tools. @Tokk thanks for pointing out this library!

Comment: @Treffynnon, did you end up writing your own? It's 2013, and your question is still very relevant

Comment: Thanks for recommending our library! We're currently updating ValidForm Builder with an average of several times a week since it's being used in some high profile projects.

For anyone interested; you should get your ValidForm Builder copy from the SVN trunk. The downloads are a bit outdated.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen, what would you say is the latest version of VFB on SVN that's safest to use? (Or should one stick with v1.0.1?)

Comment: @Baumr like I said; use the latest version available from the SVN trunk. It contains all our latest features and bug fixes. We're very strict in quality control when it comes to committing stuff to the trunk. 1.0.1 has some issues that are fixed in the head revision. In about two weeks from now we'll deploy a new packaged release.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen, OK thanks — will do that. What put me off is [this warning](http://code.google.com/p/validformbuilder/): **"These nightly build versions are updated with high frequency but aren't supposed to be used in production environments and are considered 'beta'."** But the new additions seem like really awesome features, good work!

Comment: True, that is the basic disclaimer. Nevertheless, we are actually using the nightly build in our own live (large) projects which is some sort of indicator for you and other people who read this, that the nightly build at this point is good for production.

Comment: It's been another year now and we're on a stable v3.0 composer-installable GitHub-based project. [Check it out](https://github.com/neverwoods/validformbuilder/releases)

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATED for 2017**

[Agile UI](https://github.com/atk4/ui) is a PHP UI component library (and successor of atk4.3) including things like:

- Interractive Forms
- CRUD
- Grid
- Menus
- Paginators
- see more at http://ui.agiletoolkit.org/demos/index.php

All components have a consistent and simple PHP interface:

```
$form = new \atk4\ui\Form();
$layout->add($form);
$form->setModel(new Country($db));
```

If you prefer CRUD just use `\atk4\ui\CRUD`. Agile UI also offers tools for adding custom components.

[image]

Comparing with alternative software:

- Outputs HTML for form `$form->render()` or for entire web app.
- Automatically styled with [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/)
- Server-side validation, displays errors inline.
- Form layouts
- Includes support jQuery UI.
- Stores data through [Agile Data](https://git.io/ad), SQL, NoSQL
- Support custom HTML templates
- Open-source and licensed under MIT

Comment: The possibilities are endless with Agile, A must try framework now with proper video tutorials too.

Comment: It doesn't feel right to write Javascript code and logic in PHP..

Comment: You don't. You write it in JS. You bind code through PHP.

Answer (score 1):

An option I have come across is [jFormer](http://www.jformer.com/), but it has a very short history and the PHP code is less than desirable with a massive 3000 line file full of multiple classes. It doesn't take a modular approach.

Comment: There appears to be a fatal flaw in the jFormer library. Unless I am missing something you cannot submit a form without javascript as the submit input is of `type="button"` and not `type="submit"`. I might contact the creators to find out more.

Comment: Ticket opened on their github page regarding no JS submissions: https://github.com/kirkouimet/jformer/issues#issue/1

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are the problems with running client-side validation in [HTML_QuickForm2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm2)?

It needs a **quickform.js** file to work. The file is installed with the package but is *not* automatically included in the form output. I've recently updated [the docs](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-quickform2.javascript.php) to make this issue more obvious.

Also QF2 had a couple of releases since your question, a few JS-related bugs were squashed. Consider giving it another try: we are targeting a stable release Really Soon Now and would love feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst looking through the PEAR repository today I noticed that [HTML_QuickForm2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm2) has made a new release that now supports client side validation as well. It does not use jQuery though and they have written their own JS framework for the job.

Comment: I have only given this some minor testing, but I am unable to get the client side validation to work.

Comment: Did you get the client-side validation workin'?

Comment: @Baumr I didn't continue with it to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) framework. It provides a Model-View-Controller layer and automatic form generation out of the model. There are many validation options. But I think there is some modification needed to integrate JQuery client-side validation too.

Comment: I had been looking at just the form component of Symfony before. I am still unsure why all the developers of these jQuery/PHP libraries don't take a decent well tested PHP form library to build upon. You could then use jQuery tools to do form validation and date pickers etc.

Comment: You are right. Currently Symfony2 is developed and should offer a better modular structure, which allows you to use only the bits from the framework you need (these are called [bundles](http://symfony2bundles.org/)). But it is still unfinished.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon a jQuery plugin called [jquery-ahm](http://www.jqueryahm.com/examples). It moves the validation logic to the server, but executes it at the client with JavaScript. At the bottom of the page you see an example for form validation.

Html markup:

```
<form id="form" action="/a.form" method="post" class="ahm">
<p>Name</p>
<input name="name" id="name" value="" type="text">
<p>Email</p>
<input name="email" id="email" value="" type="text">
<p>Password</p>
<input name="password" id="password" value="" type="text">
<br><input value="Submit Form" type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
// catch errors
foreach (array("name", "email", "password") as $key) {
    if (empty($_POST[$key])) {
        $error["#$key/addClass"] = "error";
        $error["#$key/after"]    = "<span class="error">Please enter $key</span>";  
    }
}

// get response
if (!empty($error)) {
    $reset["input.error/removeClass"] = "error";
    $reset["span.error/remove"]       = "";
    $response = $reset + $error;    // reset errors before applying new ones
} else {
    $response["#form/replaceWith"] = "<strong>Form successfully submitted</strong>";
}

// return response
return $response;
?>
```

Result:

[image: Form output]

Comment: I have seen the approach in a few plugins. Unfortunately to my mind this doesn't solve the issue because the user is still forced to wait for the validation of the form. The JS validation I envisage should mark the field valid as the user types into the box and you can't really make an ajax request on every keypress! :) It is a nice way round the problem though and requires only one set of validation logic so is more DRY, but...

Comment: @Treffynnon, how did you find that this compared to ValidForm Builder?

Comment: @Alp, looks really cool — but the demo doesn't validate the email address. And how does it handle injected/hacky code? But sadly, it **seems that it doesn't work with JS turned off.**

Comment: @Baumr I didn't use it because it wasn't performing the validation in JS.