# Jformer questions

Tags: php, jquery

I am looking for some help with jFormer.

The way my site works a form cannot submit to the same place it was built,

yet looking at the demo code it seems that this is how it has to work?

Is this true?

Comment: try setting the action to an empty string `action=""`. This will submit the form to the same page

Comment: You might be interested in this analysis I recently did of the form libraries. jFormer ain't that great and they still have not responded to simple bugs I issued a week ago now. The forms won't even submit without JS enabled! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362842/a-php-and-jquery-form-creation-and-validation-library-available

Comment: @Chris he is asking for the exact opposite of your suggestion.

Comment: @Treffynnon ah. well then set `action` to the page that handles the form submission

Comment: Have you had any joy with this? I would also be curious to hear how you are finding jFormer in general perhaps you could comment on the jFormer answer in the question I linked earlier/above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362842/a-php-and-jquery-form-creation-and-validation-library-available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No guarantees as I am unable to test it myself, but you could try:

```
$contactForm = new JFormer('contactForm', array('action' => 'my_page.php'));
```

Items added into the array passed to the `JFormer` constructor are supposed to be added as attributes to the form tag from what I can see in the code. See https://github.com/kirkouimet/jformer/blob/master/source/development/php/JFormer.php

**Update**

Actually it looks like I was looking at the incorrect class as they have two classes in the `JForm.php` file when you would expect there to only be the actual `JFormer` class in there. They have a `JFormElement` class at the top of the file! Still I cannot readily see if it might still work or not.

The documentation is lack lustre and the inline comments are worse.